# Best way to launch scheduled jobs for a python script (bot)

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, celery, bots, celerybeat

I'm trying to build a Twitter bot that does a set of periodic actions that have different time intervals/periods. So I was trying to come up with a good solution to handle a group of scheduled tasks that have different frequencies.

For example, I need to do the following tasks:

- Every 15 minutes do task 1.
- Every hour do task 2.
- Every day do task 3.
- Once a week do task 4.

I've tought about using cron jobs but it seems messy, either by using one cron job every 15 minutes and checking which task needs to be executed or having separated cron entries for each task.

I wanted something better, so I read that Celery could be used to schedule periodic tasks, but I'm having troubles to wrap my head around the workers and the messaging queue.

Are there any other alternatives?
Which one do you think it's better to make the program easier to maintain and extend?
I've used cron before, but for very simple tasks. Are there any resources about how to correctly setup the cron for a case like this.

Comment: if the answer provided is helpful, please accept it, or update for further help ;)

Comment: @olamotte Sorry for the delay, I'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a deeper look at cron, as it's supported by so many OS, and extensible by simple scripts. Here is a [simple crontab generator](http://www.tdscripts.com/webmaster_utilities/cron-generator.php)